# Updating SDK of an app written in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I am doing a task for a client which is based on updating SDK. I have to make sure everything is working properly before updating application on the app store. This app has to be compatible with iOS 10.1 and 9.0 as well.

1) Is it enough if I just change deployment target in Xcode 8 to 9.0, to make it compatible with older version?

2) All pods are in obj-c, so to update them do I have to search for the latest version or find swift alternatives?

Comment: it's recommend to update all pods because various changes will be done regarding iOS 10/9. No need to add swift version of pods

Comment: Okey. Thanks. What about compatibility with older version?

Comment: You should check the readme of Pods where you downloaded it.Now most t of the pods giving support from 7 , i think thats  fits your requirement